# Throwing a ball using Box2D and AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

**PART 1** Does anyone have any idea how to create a ball that when you drag it and let go it throws itself in the same direction with physics? I've already created the ball as a sprite and everything and made it into a physics object. Just needed to know how to do the above. I was thinking of using ontouch motion events and stuff but I think that will only make the ball move to where my finger is and then drop where I release it without any velocity.

I'm not talking about an angry birds style sling, i'm talking about touching the ball then swiping the finger, then the ball goes in the same direction as the swipe.

**PART 2**
I've done a bit of research and found out that to make a physics object move by swiping it is necessary to use Mouse Joints. I've got everything to work so far but I just have one small problem now. Basically as my game is now, if I click anywhere on the scene the ball moves towards it in a physics kind of way using this code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
            mouseJointDef.target.set(ball1Body.getWorldCenter());
            mouseJoint = (MouseJoint) mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(mouseJointDef);
            final Vector2 vec = Vector2Pool.obtain(pSceneTouchEvent.getX()
                    / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,
                    pSceneTouchEvent.getY()
                            / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
            mouseJoint.setTarget(vec);
            Vector2Pool.recycle(vec);
        } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
            final Vector2 vec = Vector2Pool.obtain(pSceneTouchEvent.getX()
                    / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,
                    pSceneTouchEvent.getY()
                            / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
            mouseJoint.setTarget(vec);
            Vector2Pool.recycle(vec);
            return true;
        } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionCancel()
                || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionOutside()
                || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
            mPhysicsWorld.destroyJoint(mouseJoint);
        }
        return true;

    }
```

How would i change this about to get it so that when the ball is swiped it will move in the direction of the swipe instead of clicking on the scene.

Thank You

Comment: Where's your code that shows you tried before with it?

Comment: Keep track of the position of the touch in recent steps, eg. the last five steps or so, and use that to give the body a velocity when it is released.

Comment: I gave an answer to basically this exact same question.  Here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540858/how-to-throw-fling-the-ball-by-swiping-on-it-using-andengine/20549429#20549429

Comment: I know what your saying but, i was reading another answer and they where saying that with physics objects i have to use mouse joints instead. Also i'm not supposed to refer to the sprite but instead the body.